# How to work with Android SIP for two way voice calling

Tags: java, android, xml

As i am new to SIP, so not able to understand it. Kindly, help me regarding it.

I have downloaded the sample project 'SipDemo' which is available  in the Android SDK, but not able to understand since it is showing 'Registration failed.  Please check settings'

Android Code is as follows:

WalkieTalkieActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.net.sip.*;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class WalkieTalkieActivity extends Activity implements
    View.OnTouchListener {

public String sipAddress = null;

public SipManager manager = null;
public SipProfile me = null;
public SipAudioCall call = null;
public IncomingCallReceiver callReceiver;

private static final int CALL_ADDRESS = 1;
private static final int SET_AUTH_INFO = 2;
private static final int UPDATE_SETTINGS_DIALOG = 3;
private static final int HANG_UP = 4;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.walkietalkie);

    ToggleButton pushToTalkButton =(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.pushToTalk);
    pushToTalkButton.setOnTouchListener(this);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
    callReceiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();
    this.registerReceiver(callReceiver, filter);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    initializeManager();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    initializeManager();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (call != null) {
        call.close();
    }

    closeLocalProfile();

    if (callReceiver != null) {
        this.unregisterReceiver(callReceiver);
    }
}

public void initializeManager() {
    if (manager == null) {
        manager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
    }

    initializeLocalProfile();
}

public void initializeLocalProfile() {
    if (manager == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (me != null) {
        closeLocalProfile();
    }

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String username = prefs.getString("namePref", "");
    String domain = prefs.getString("domainPref", "");
    String password = prefs.getString("passPref", "");

    if (username.length() == 0 || domain.length() == 0
            || password.length() == 0) {
        showDialog(UPDATE_SETTINGS_DIALOG);
        return;
    }

    try {
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username,
                domain);
        builder.setPassword(password);
        me = builder.build();

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i,
                Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        manager.open(me, pi, null);

        manager.setRegistrationListener(me.getUriString(),
                new SipRegistrationListener() {
                    public void onRegistering(String   localProfileUri) {
                        updateStatus("Registering with SIP Server...");
                    }

                    public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri,
                            long expiryTime) {
                        updateStatus("Ready");
                    }

                    public void onRegistrationFailed(
                            String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                            String errorMessage) {
                        updateStatus("Registration failed.  Please check settings.");

                    }
                });
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        updateStatus("Connection Error.");
    } catch (SipException se) {
        updateStatus("Connection error.");
    }
}

public void closeLocalProfile() {
    if (manager == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (me != null) {
            manager.close(me.getUriString());
        }
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        Log.d("WalkieTalkieActivity/onDestroy",
                "Failed to close local profile.", ee);
    }
}

public void initiateCall() {

    updateStatus(sipAddress);

    try {
        SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                call.startAudio();
                call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                call.toggleMute();
                updateStatus(call);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                updateStatus("Ready.");
            }
        };

        call = manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(), sipAddress,
                listener, 30);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall",
                "Error when trying to close manager.", e);
        if (me != null) {
            try {
                manager.close(me.getUriString());
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall",
                        "Error when trying to close manager.", ee);
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (call != null) {
            call.close();
        }
    }
}

public void updateStatus(final String status) {
    // Be a good citizen. Make sure UI changes fire on the UI thread.
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TextView labelView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sipLabel);
            labelView.setText(status);
        }
    });
}

public void updateStatus(SipAudioCall call) {
    String useName = call.getPeerProfile().getDisplayName();
    if (useName == null) {
        useName = call.getPeerProfile().getUserName();
    }
    updateStatus(useName + "@" + call.getPeerProfile().getSipDomain());
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (call == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && call != null
            && call.isMuted()) {
        call.toggleMute();
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
            && !call.isMuted()) {
        call.toggleMute();
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, CALL_ADDRESS, 0, "Call someone");
    menu.add(0, SET_AUTH_INFO, 0, "Edit your SIP Info.");
    menu.add(0, HANG_UP, 0, "End Current Call.");

    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case CALL_ADDRESS:
        showDialog(CALL_ADDRESS);
        break;
    case SET_AUTH_INFO:
        updatePreferences();
        break;
    case HANG_UP:
        if (call != null) {
            try {
                call.endCall();
            } catch (SipException se) {
                Log.d("WalkieTalkieActivity/onOptionsItemSelected",
                        "Error ending call.", se);
            }
            call.close();
        }
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case CALL_ADDRESS:

        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View textBoxView = factory.inflate(
                R.layout.call_address_dialog, null);
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Call Someone.")
                .setView(textBoxView)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                EditText textField = (EditText) (textBoxView
                                        .findViewById(R.id.calladdress_edit));
                                sipAddress = textField.getText().toString();
                                initiateCall();

                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                // Noop.
                            }
                        }).create();

    case UPDATE_SETTINGS_DIALOG:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Please update your SIP Account Settings.")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                updatePreferences();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                // Noop.
                            }
                        }).create();
    }
    return null;
}

public void updatePreferences() {
    Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
            SipSettings.class);
    startActivity(settingsActivity);
 }
  }
```

SipSettings.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class SipSettings extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Note that none of the preferences are actually defined here.
    // They're all in the XML file res/xml/preferences.xml.
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

}
}
```

IncomingCallReceiver.java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.sip.*;
import android.util.Log;

public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SipAudioCall incomingCall = null;
    try {

        SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, SipProfile caller)  {
                try {
                    call.answerCall(30);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        WalkieTalkieActivity wtActivity = (WalkieTalkieActivity) context;

        incomingCall = wtActivity.manager.takeAudioCall(intent, listener);
        incomingCall.answerCall(30);
        incomingCall.startAudio();
        incomingCall.setSpeakerMode(true);
        if (incomingCall.isMuted()) {
            incomingCall.toggleMute();
        }

        wtActivity.call = incomingCall;

        wtActivity.updateStatus(incomingCall);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (incomingCall != null) {
            incomingCall.close();
        }
    }
}

}
```

res\layout\walkietalkie.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="12dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sipLabel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/pushToTalk"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_record"
        android:text="@+string/talk"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="" />
 </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

res\layout\call_address_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/calladdress_view"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
    android:text="@+string/contactAddress"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/calladdress_edit"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:capitalize="none"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

res\xml\preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<EditTextPreference
    android:name="SIP Username"
    android:summary="Username for your SIP Account"
    android:defaultValue=""
    android:title="Enter Username"
    android:key="namePref" />
<EditTextPreference
    android:name="SIP Domain"
    android:summary="Domain for your SIP Account"
    android:defaultValue=""
    android:title="Enter Domain"
    android:key="domainPref" />
<EditTextPreference
    android:name="SIP Password"
    android:summary="Password for your SIP Account"
    android:defaultValue=""
    android:title="Enter Password"
    android:key="passPref"
    android:password="true" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.sip" >

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="SipDemo" >
    <activity
        android:name=".WalkieTalkieActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SipSettings"
        android:label="set_preferences" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver"
        android:label="Call Receiver" />
</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="true" />

</manifest>
```

Please guide me, so that i can understand how to work with SIP and proceed to work on two way voice calling.

Thanxs in advance

Comment: Start from the very beginning https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol

Comment: @EvZ How to work with it in Android project for two way voice calling

Comment: Sip IS two way voice calling. I don't understand your problem. You failed to register means you got the sip account info wrong. Maybe wrong user ID ,password, or server ip.